# How to store values from a dictionary into another dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to store the values in an existing dictionary into another dictionary while traversing through all the items? How can this be done? I have tried to access all items using this:

```
res = {
  "responseCode": 0,
  "responseDesc": [
    {
      "city_id": 1,
      "city_name": "Mumbai",
      "description": "Mumbai",
      "latitude": 18.987807,
      "longitude": 72.836447,
      "total_trips": 0
    }
  ]
}
temp = {}
for responseDesc in res :
    temp = (res[responseDesc])
```

The above statement in for loop throws an error. If I try to print the values instead of storing them in the temp dictionary it shows them correctly.
How can I achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you want to store the values it should be temp[responseDesc] = (res[responseDesc]) existing code shouldn't throw error too. you will get the last key value into temp.

Comment: thanks @PrayalankarAshutosh. it copies all the item in the temp dictionary. I want just the 'responseDesc' items to be copied into temp.

Comment: than its should be temp = res['responseDesc']

Comment: The keys to your dictionary are strings, but you're passing it a variable name `responseDesc` without the quotes, while you should pass it `'responseDesc'`

Comment: Do you want the type of the value for "responseDesc" to be a list instead of a dictionary?

Comment: @DavidLee    dictionary will also work because the values inside responseDesc are in format of dictionary

Answer (score 1):

try below code

```
temp = {}
for responseDesc in res :
    if responseDesc =='responseDesc':
        temp = res[responseDesc]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking to take a copy in the easiest possible way, use `temp=dict(res)`

If you are looking at iterating through all the nested layers of the json you can:

1. Use a nested function
2. Use a for loop with a stack

If you want to iterate through the responseDesc array: `for responseDesc in res['responseDesc']:`

Comment: thanks. This helps. I want to display all these values on the browser. so I was thinking of storing them in a dict. But if it try to do that inside the for loop, it throws error saying dict in unhashable.

Comment: Yeah you cannot iterate through a dictionary. You can iterate through the keys() or items() of the dictionary. You can also iterate through res['responseDesc'] which is an array contained inside a dictionary

Comment: There's some information here you might find useful: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques